# How to hide createAccount select by default • Charge 2 Plugin

Tags: plugin-charge

I'm adding a basic annual subscription to a portion of a website.

I have Registration Behaviour set to
Always - creates an account for all guest payments

But on the subscription form the createAccount select still appears (Save my account, No don't create an account".

I'm including the customerDetails fields like this:

```
{% include 'charge/_includes/inputs/customerDetails' with { 'registerGuest' : true }%}
```

I see the form logic in customerDetails.html but that doesn't feel like something that should be edited.

I want to remove the select, since I should always be creating a new account by default OR I want to replace it with a hidden field.

Comment: What's wrong with editing the html?

Comment: @RobinSchambach That's the solution I landed on.

Answer (score 2):

Eventually I just edited customerDetails.html and swapped out the select with a hidden field. Done.

```
{{ forms.hidden({
    name: 'createAccount',
    id: 'createAccount',
    value: 'yes'
}) }}
```